# Why does Apache tika with an get .mp4 file respond with a content type of "video/quicktime"?

Tags: java, image, mp4, apache-tika

I use this function to get files contentType ，when use the .jpg file receive "image/jpg". use .mp4 receive "video/quicktime"

```
public static String detectMediaType(String fileName,byte[] data) {
    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    Detector detector = parser.getDetector();
    Metadata md = new Metadata();
    md.add(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileName);
    try{
        MediaType mediaType = detector.detect(inputStream, md);
        return mediaType.toString();
    }catch (IOException ex){
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to detect mediaType for file: " + fileName,ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: How many mp4 files did you test? May be the file extension is just wrong and it is really a Quicktime container? You should use a hex editor and check the file header.

Comment: Are you aware that all MP4 files are a subtype of QuickTime?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2935?focusedCommentId=16931467#comment-16931467 for details of the work that someone needs to do to solve this - needs a new Tika detector for the MP4 container type

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was wondering, why I still got "video/quicktime" as Mimetype after using the answers above. So just to conclude everything:

- use a Parser to detect Metadata (like in the first answer)
- use TikaInputStream (like in the second answer), but **don't** try to reuse it
- include a specific parser for your case in your dependencies (in this case it is the *org.apache.tika.parser.mp4.MP4Parser*

  ```
   Tika tika = new Tika();
   String detectedType;

   try (
     TikaInputStream parserInputStream = TikaInputStream.get(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
     TikaInputStream detectionInputStream = TikaInputStream.get(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
   ) {
     // reading metadata from file, important for video type detection (quicktime, mp4, ...)
     Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
     BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
     Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
     ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
     parser.parse(parserInputStream, handler, metadata, context);
     // read the type
     // would like to reuse the stream from above (used by parser), but this can end in a wrong mimetype
     // parserInputStream.reset();
     detectedType = tika.detect(detectionInputStream, metadata);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
     detectedType = tika.detect(bytes);
     log.warn("Could not read MimeType of file '{}' using Metadata, using fallback detection: '{}'", file.getOriginalFilename(), detectedType);
   }
  ```

Dependencies, for example in Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
  <artifactId>tika-parser-audiovideo-module</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected because you are using tika detector functionality which for mp4 or for other QuickTime formats returns generic 'video/quicktime'. If you need to get exact type like 'video/mp4' you should additionally use tika parser, for example:

```
if (mediaType.equals(MediaType.video("quicktime"))) {
    Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
    parser.parse(inputStream, handler, metadata, context);
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me. There is probably a real difference between video/mp4 and video/quicktime.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Tikas DefaultDetector.

The solution, as indicated here: https://tika.apache.org/2.3.0/detection.html (under "Container Aware Detection"), is to use `TikaInputStream`, instead of a standard `InputStream`.

```
detector.detect(TikaInputStream.get(inputStream), metadata);
```

- Don't forget to close the streams.
- Also ensure that a `tika-parsers-*` jar is in the class path.